# Why is `sData` a non-nil value?

Tags: string, search, lua, ptokax

Execution of the code is [here on eval.in](http://eval.in/15723)

```
sMessage = "<hjpotter92> +help|"
local _, _, sCmd, sData = sMessage:find( "%b<>%s[%+%-%*%/%!%#%?](%w+)%s?(.*)|" )
print( _, sData, sCmd  )
```

The output of `print` says the my `sData` is a value with empty string.

**Why is this value not `nil`?** I created an entire project based on `sData` being `nil` for such a case, and I find that it is not so.

---

I've resolved the trouble by using this block

```
if sData:len() == 0 then 
    sData = nil 
end
```

So, I'm not seeking a solution to make this work. I'm just asking, why is it not a `nil` value?

Comment: I would fill in the small components first, before working on the broader project scope. That being said, to my knowledge, `find` never returns `nil`.

Comment: @Telthien You might want to [reconsider that statement](http://eval.in/15744).

Comment: I retracted my answer, since now that I understand what you're asking, I don't know what causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it should be `nil`?
You are getting successful match of pattern `.*` with empty string.
`nil` means "no match found".
[example](http://eval.in/15748)

Comment: Then there is no other way to use find/match so that `sData` will be a `nil`? It doesn't actually affect much though, since I have used the if-statement instead.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Empty string and `nil` are conceptually different objects, why you want to mix them up?